# Youtube API V3 not recognizing playlistID filter

Tags: coldfusion, youtube-api

It may be that I am reading the API docs completely wrong, but here we go.

I send a GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems. In that request, I have the AUTHORIZATION header, and two parameters:

```
"PART" : "contentDetails",
"PLAYLISTID" : "UUy8_GJ_ZQ2SHm909UJ1AK-Q"
```

I know my authorization is correct, because I'm using the same auth header to get and receive Analytics requests with no problem.

According to [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), either ID or playlistID MUST be included. But I get a "No filter selected" error 400 back when I send this request.

```
{ "error" : { "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ { "domain" : "youtube.parameter",
        "location" : "",
        "locationType" : "parameter",
        "message" : "No filter selected.",
        "reason" : "missingRequiredParameter"
      } ],
  "message" : "No filter selected."
   } 
}
```

If I change the PlaylistID parameter to ID, the request successfully completes and returns an empty array (empty because that video ID obviously doesn't exist.)

Is this an API bug? Is the API case sensitive? (From what I can see, CFHTTP uppercases the param names even though I wrap them with LCase)

Update:

Code here: https://gist.github.com/mborn319/13d7b9b03db10d97cd16

Apologies, I'm not sure how best to share 200 lines of CFML.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: As per @Leigh: it's hard to comment on what might be wrong with your code if we can't see it ;-)

Comment: I don't know enough CFML to comment on that, but if you do a simple request to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=UUy8_GJ_ZQ2SHm909UJ1AK-Q&key=YOUR_KEY you get your results so I doubt it's an API bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, the problem is the uppercased PLAYLIST ID param.

As you can see, this request works pretty fine:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=UUy8_GJ_ZQ2SHm909UJ1AK-Q&access_token=[putValidAccessTokenHere]

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
    "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/1T4SJss5RstUWWw6S4NPUKDWL-c\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
            "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/s2P7FNuP_oK0sax4SB_fU9BVaLo\"",
            "id": "UUeEJED-0K6VNZf3zbi8n5FA7Qu41XY55_",
            "contentDetails": {
                "videoId": "Y-Ft354b_vI"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you make the same query with PLAYLISTID you will get your error output:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&PLAYLISTID=UUy8_GJ_ZQ2SHm909UJ1AK-Q&access_token=[putValidAccessTokenHere]

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "youtube.parameter",
                "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
                "message": "No filter selected.",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": ""
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "No filter selected."
    }
}
```

But i am sorry, i can't tell you how to post params with CF in lowercases (is it even possible?) but here is a reference to some CF code. They use the old data api but they fetch data via get-request. Maybe the treatment of params differs in this case: http://davidosomething.com/blog/quick-access-to-the-youtube-api-with-coldfusion/

Comment: My apologies, I should have accepted this as the answer. I have since run into other APIs, such as Mailchimp, being case-sensitive with certain parameters, such as `"Authorization: OAuth"` vs. `"Authorization: "Oauth"` headers, which is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the API is case-sensitive, you have to ensure ColdFusion maintains casing, which can be a little frustrating since ColdFusion isn't strict.

If you use dot notation to specify the key name in the structure, CF almost always uppercases it.

But if you specify the key name using bracket notation, the casing is maintained.

```
<cfset args.foo = "...">  key will be stored/transmitted as uppercase FOO
 vs.
<cfset args["foo"] = "...">  key will be stored/transmitted as lowercase foo


<cfset args["UPPERCASE"]="UPPERCASE">
<cfset args["lowercase"]="lowercase">
<cfset args["CamelCase"]="CamelCase">
```

So you should be able to create a structure with your arguments, using brackets

```
<cfset data["part"] = "contentDetails">
<cfset data["playlistId"] = "UUy8_GJ_ZQ2SHm909UJ1AK-Q">
```

And then loop over your args as before

```
<cfhttp url="#arguments.url#" method="#arguments.type#" result="httpResult">
    <cfloop item="curArg" collection="#data#">
        <cfhttpparam name="#curArg#" value="#data[curArg]#" type="url" />
    </cfloop>
</cfhttp>
```

The API should then receive the params in the proper case.

```
<cfdump var="#DeserializeJson(httpResult.filecontent.tostring())#">
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that technique would maintain casing. Extremely helpful!

Comment: fyi : camelCase starts with lowercase letter, PascelCase has  upper first letter